# How do I perform math using TinyDB? (App Inventor 2)

Tags: app-inventor

I am trying to use TinyDB in order to store a value on one screen and display it on another. On the second screen, I want to add 1 to the number stored with TinyDB on the first screen. However, when I try to do this, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code for the two screens.

**Screen1**
[image]

**Screen2**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already loaded the available computers in `Screen2.Initialize` into label `computersAvail.Text`. Therefore in the `Button1.Click` event first add 1 like this

```
set computersAvail.Text to get computersAvail.Text + 1
```

and to store the updated available computers in `TinyDB` then use the following block

```
TinyDB.StoreValue "Computers"
                  get computersAvail.Text
```

btw. it helps to first [do the tutorials](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html) to learn the basics of App Inventor...
also see [this link for "the lost souls"](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/NBKl_SP8ab0/bc7BQOUoPXgJ)...

Comment: When I open Screen2 again using one of the buttons on Screen1, it resets the value to the one on Screen1, as I have programmed it to do. How do I stop it from resetting? (This is not vital though)

Comment: As you can see from the blocks in screen1, once you click button1 again after coming back from screen2, it goes back to 12. I know how to store it, but I don't know how to store the new number of computers into screen1. Do I need to use global variables?

Comment: you have to read the stored value in Screen1... this is some very basic stuff... see also https://groups.google.com/d/msg/programming-with-app-inventor/w7PAggKauz8/aa2YHe5cTKIJ

Comment: Taifun, I really appreciate your help but I extremely confused on how to save the individual number of computers for each separate room. Please can you help? Thanks.

Comment: To reiterate, the new values for a building from screen2 which the user changes cannot be called up when they go back to screen1 and select a different building, and then go back to the original. (I.E. Stored value in screen2 can't be called up because screen1 resets to the default value, don't know how to work around this).

Comment: As already said, you **first have to read the stored values in Screen1**. Btw. for new questions, please use the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button

Comment: Sorry @Taifun I am still unsure what to do. I will make a new question with the app-inventor tag and post some images.